# zend db table model and query multiple tables

Tags: zend-framework

Just like in codeigniter model class, can we have multiple methods calling different tables in zend framework model that extends zend_db_table_abstract ?

> protected $_name = table_name

when defining table name like that, Is there a way to query multiple table having no affect of that protected property ? I am mainly concern about this because I want to have model for homepage which will deal with frontend website and fetch data from different table so that i don't have to touch backend db-table models.

Comment: Why don't you use `DbTable—>Mapper—>Model`? than you'll have `Zend_Db_Table` per table, and use them in mappers to craete models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also access the DB adapter member in the table and query it directly, specifying a table name of your choice.

For instance, for a `select`, you can do something like the following:

```
$select = $this->getAdapter()->select();
$select->from('tableName', $fields);
// ...
$results = $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
```

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

Try `protected $_name = array(1=>'table1', 2=>'table2', /*etc...*/);`

And add a `foreach()` to your code when the query is made, like this:

```
foreach ($_name as $table)
{
    // execute your query
}
```

It should work, I used this in my CMS for the AdminZone...